# How can I count the number of folders in a drive using Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line

I need to organise an external HDD such that there is no more than 500 folders on it. Ubuntu's "Properties" pane shows only the file count, not the folder count.

Is there a simple command line that will tell me the number of subdirectories?

I need to count recursively, and the drive is an external HDD mounted at `/media/MUSIC/`.
It's for a car stereo system whose documentation says it only reads the first 500 folders.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Navigate to your drive (Can open a terminal window there) and simply execute:

```
ls -lR | grep ^d | wc -l
```

Comment: This appears to provide a more correct number than the answer I accepted 3 years ago. It counted the directory I was in whereas this done not.

Comment: I see different numbers as well, but not too different.

Comment: Personally I prefer the `grep -c` over the `wc -l`. Maybe it's just me.

Comment: The above will overcount if any directory entry contains the sequence `\nd` (where `\n` is the NL character).

Comment: Toby is right, [`ls` output is not supposed to be piped](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/44425). Moreover this will be much slower because it has to output the whole tree and then run grep through it

Comment: This will ignore (i.e., not count) any directories whose names begin with **`.`**.  Give ``ls`` the ``-A`` option.

Answer (score 38):

- Find all folders in total, including subdirectories:

  ```
  find /mount/point -type d | wc -l
  ```
- Find all folders in the root directory (not including subdirectories):

  ```
  find /mount/point -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | wc -l
  ```

  The `-maxdepth 1` confines the command to the current directory
  (i.e., it forbids recursion); the `-mindepth 1` causes it
  not to include the top-level directory (the mount point) itself.

Comment: That first one is exactly what I'm after.
Thanks!

Comment: @Dean: yeah, i've used it for counting directories in my music collection before too. :)  for braggin' rights, count your MP3s: *find /mount/point -type f | grep -i mp3 | wc -l*

Comment: I've already used *find . -name \*.jpg* and *find . -name \*.jpg -exec rm -rf {} \;* with various filetypes to clear out everything except the MP3's and WAV's, (well, I think everything at least). Is there a way to search NOT. I.E. return everything within the folder except MP3's and WAV's?

Comment: @Dean: yeah, i don't know the *find* syntax offhand, but i'd usually use *grep -v* for that: *find /mount/pt -type f | grep -vi mp3 | grep -vi wav | wc -l*  ...(and <i></i> doesn't work in comments, use `*foo*` to italicize: *foo* )

Comment: @Dean: i think you'd just use `find /path -not -iname '*.mp3' | wc -l` to filter MP3s, or to get both MP3s and WAVs use `find /path -not -iname '*.mp3' -not -iname '*.wav' | wc -l`

Comment: Needed to add the *-type f* in order for it to ignore folders as well, but congrats! I just found a whole bunch of m4a files I had no idea about... Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Newlines are valid characters in directory names. I suggest letting `find` print a character for each directory found and then letting `wc` count those characters:

```
find /mount/point -mindepth 1 -type d -printf 'a' | wc -c
```

Specify `-mindepth 1` to avoid counting the mount point directory itself.

Comment: Counting things on a hard disk is probably an I/O-bound operation; this might be true even for a faster device like an SSD.  But, if CPU time is a concern, you should use ``wc -c`` rather than ``wc -l``.  ``wc -c`` will use less slightly CPU time because it doesn’t need to look at every byte (and ``wc -l`` does).  And then, of course, if you’re counting bytes, you can use any one-byte string; it doesn’t have to be newline.

Comment: @Scott Good point. I've now updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following
[but see below]:

```
ls -1 -Ap /mount/point | grep "/" | wc -l
```

Note: the first option to `ls` is <kbd>dash</kbd> <kbd>one</kbd>,
but the option to `wc` is <kbd>dash</kbd> <kbd>lower case L</kbd>.

This will print a one-column list of the current directory
(including **`.`** entries other than **`.`** and **`..`** themselves),
with trailing slashes for items that are subdirectories,
then count the lines with the slashes.

If you want to look at the entire directory tree
(i.e., look at the directory *recursively*),
you should probably go with [quack quixote's answer](https://superuser.com/q/129088/150988#129090),
as it is a little more explicit,
but I've corrected mine (after taking quack's suggestions into account):

```
ls -ARp /mount/point | grep '/$' | wc -l
```

Comment: Need to add -R to go recursive (sorry for failing to mention), and need to specify the path to ls, but yeah, this works:
ls -1 -p -R /media/MUSIC/ | grep "/" | wc -l
Thanks!

Comment: After trying both this and quack quixote's suggestion, I got 2 different results... I'm inclined to believe the other one. Thanks anyway!

Comment: you don't need the `-1` since *ls* will detect the pipe and won't format columns.  also you can grab recursive listings with `-R`, but then you probably want to grep for `"/$"` to only match trailing slashes (or the count will be off).  final version: `ls -Rp | grep "/$" | wc -l`

Comment: the *find* version i posted will count `.` (ie `/mount/point`) in its count, the *ls* version in my above comment won't.  those counts differ by 1, tho you could use `/mount/point/*` in the *find* command to correct that (assuming no hidden dot-directories).

Comment: i'm not sure why you got the two differnent results, but @quack's method will include "hidden" directories (ie. those that begin with '.').

Comment: @stuntmouse: either because it's not including subfolders at all (your orig version), or because, with -R, it prints the relative paths as a sort of header, and *grep "/"* will match that header -- so all folders are counted twice.  that's why my earlier comment suggested *grep "/$"* ; that will only match slashes at the end of the output.

Comment: btw, feel free to incorporate suggestions from these comments into your answer (use the "edit" link).  Super User is about good questions and good answers, using comment feedback to make your answer better is encouraged.  welcome to the site!

Comment: thanks for the welcome @quack.  also, i've included your suggestions in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I have written [`ffcnt`](https://github.com/the8472/ffcnt) to speed up recursive file counting under specific circumstances: rotational disks and filesystems that support extent mapping.

It can be an order of magnitude faster than than `ls` or `find` based approaches.

Answer (score 2):

I have found `du --inodes` useful, but I'm not sure which version of `du` it requires. On Ubuntu 17.10, the following works:

```
du --inodes      # all files and subdirectories
du --inodes -s   # summary
du --inodes -d 2 # depth 2 at most
```

Combine with `| sort -nr` to sort descending by number of containing inodes.

Answer (score 1):

When there is a large number of directories, tools like `tree` might take an eternity to finish or even hang, so you might want to use something more efficient.

The most efficient way to count the directories I can think of would be the following, since `find` will only print one `.` for each folder found instead of the complete path and file name and `wc` only needs to iterate over the number of characters:

```
find /mount/point -type d -printf '.' |wc -c
```

To exclude `/mount/point` itself from the calculation and only count the sub directories:

```
find /mount/point -mindepth 1 -type d -printf '.' |wc -c
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `tree` to pull directory count with:

```
tree -d -R -fi --noreport | wc -l
```

Or, I'll use `find` to show bulk of the folders are located with:

```
find . -type d -printf "%h\n" | cut -d/ -f-2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Comment: Or something like:

tree | grep -e '^.*directories,'

Answer (score -2):

To find number of folders and directory in current directory, type the following command in your terminal:

```
echo */ | wc
```